# Django Query for Hierarchical Results Set

Tags: django, django-models

I have three Django models that exist in a hierarchy:

`Protocol` -> has `Test`s

`Test` -> has `Case`s

The `Test` model has a foreign key to `Protocol`, and the `Case` model has foreign keys to `Test` and `Protocol`. A pretty simple structure.

Each of these models has an attribute called owner and any user in my app can own anything. What I want to do is create a query that gives me a unique set of all of the owners of any instance of these three models. I haven't been able to find a nice way to do this in Django. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it without querying all the models individually.

```
User.objects.filter(Q(protocol__isnull=False) | Q(test__isnull=False) | Q(case__isnull=False)
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I ended up doing something quite similar.